# How to join first ordered match in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, join

I have got 2 tables like this

```
Cities:
id__| country__
--------------
_1__| 1000
_2__| 1001
_3__| 1002

Translates:
id__ | city_id  |      name       | __lang__ | _order_
-------------------------------------------------------
1____|     1    | Dnipro          | en       | 2
2____|     1    | Dnipropetrovsk  | en       | 1
3____|     1    | Ekaterinoslav   | en       | 3
```

How to join only first city_id of translates ordered by order ON id of cities?

I want the next result:

```
id__| country__ | city_id  |      name       | __lang__ | _order_
1   | 1000      |    1     |  Dnipropetrovsk |   en     |    1
```

I was trying the code like this

```
SELECT * FROM `cities` 
INNER JOIN `translates` ON `cities`.`id` = `translates`.`city_id` 
ORDER BY `order`
GROUP BY `city_id`
```

But GROUP BY ignores ORDER BY and left always the same row both with ORDER BY and without one

Comment: INNER JOIN `translates` ON `cities`.`id` = `translates`.`city_id` AND translates.order = 1

Answer (score 2):

There are a bunch of ways to do this but here's one way!

`SELECT
  cities.*,
  translates.*
FROM
  cities
INNER JOIN
  translates
ON 
  translates.city_id = cities.id
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT
    city_id, 
    MIN(order) as order
  FROM 
    translates 
  GROUP BY
    city_id
) relevant_translates
ON
  relevant_translates.city_id = translates.city_id
AND
  relevant_translates.order = translates.order
;`

The `relevant_translates` subquery gets the minimum order value for each city_id value in the translates table. And then by doing an inner join with translates, you only keep the translates values with the minimum order value. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If your `order` for each `city_id` doesn't always start at `1` then you could use a correlated subquery to get your smallest `order` `translate` record for each city:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `cities` 
  INNER JOIN `translates` t1 ON `cities`.`id` = t1.`city_id` 
WHERE `order` = (SELECT min(`order`) FROM translates WHERE t1.city_id = translates.city_id);
```

If it does start at `1` then just `WHERE order=1` and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do this:

```
SELECT c.id, c. 
FROM cities c
INNER JOIN translates t ON cities.id = t.city_id 
WHERE t.order = (SELECT MIN(order)
                     FROM translates t1 
                     WHERE t1.city_id = c.id)
```